# Why Java sees logcat path to directory as filter expression?

Tags: java, android, adb

I need to copy logcat from Android device to windows pc.
Logcat command :

> adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d > C:\logcat\logcat.log

runs successfully from command line. However, if i run it from code :

```
public void adbCommand(adbCommands theCommand) throws IOException {
        Log.info("Running ADB command : " + theCommand.get_command());

        Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(theCommand.get_command());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getErrorStream()));
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                String line;
                while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    Log.info(line);
                }
                while((line=errorReader.readLine())!=null){
                    Log.info("error: "+line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

        try {
            exec.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.info("Done");
```

the output is :

> adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d -s > C:\logcat\logcat.log  error: Invalid
>   filter expression 'C:\logcat\logcat.log'

Any ideas what is wrong here? 
Thank you!

Comment: What is the String returned  by: theCommand.get_command()

Comment: adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d > C:\logcat\logcat.log    the one is working fine from command line

Comment: Can you print out the value returned by theCommand.get_command() so we can see what the program sees when it executes?  What you type in the command line could be different from what the program has.

Comment: Print to Log.info : 2019-03-21 07:33:23,944 INFO  [Log] Running ADB command : adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d -s > C:\logcat\logcat.log  Pring to println :
adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d -s > C:\logcat\logcat.log

Answer (score 0):

Compare the print out to the manually entered String:

```
Running ADB command : adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d -s > C:\logcat\logcat.log 
Pring to println :    adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d -s > C:\logcat\logcat.log –
Manually entered:     adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d > C:\logcat\logcat.log
```

There is an extra -s

Comment: I removed it, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it work was to add 'cmd /c' before the adb command :

- cmd /c adb -s deviceUDID logcat -d > C:\logcat\logcat.txt